# Splitting service area polygons in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, service-area, network-dataset

I am doing a project in which I am looking at the areas accessible within varying distances of open subway entrances. When I created the Service Area layer for open subway entrances, I noticed some peculiar things. The polygons were designed to be split, or not overlapping.

[image]

I set cutoffs for 1324 feet, 2728 feet, and 4092 feet from the facilities, which are open subway entrances. There should be polygons for 0-1364 feet, 1364-2728 feet, and 2728-4092 feet. For the most part, this is what has happened, but in some areas, there are weird errors.

For instance, at Union Turnpike station, the polygon for the areas within 0-1364 feet of the 80th Road subway entrance, has 0 area, and I am instead in the 1364-2728 polygon.

[image]

Another error is that though I set the service polygons to be split, they are overlapping, which is incorrect.

[image]

There are also issues like this:
For the same station entrance, you have multiple overlapping polygons. For instance this entrance has polygons covering 0-1364 feet, as it supposed to, and for some reason, one from 0-1273.15. Even weirder, these two areas are very different areas.

[image]

[image]

There also several disconnected service areas that don’t make any sense. On the whole, these errors might not make much of a difference, but you never know.

[image]

This one is also very peculiar. It should not be possible for a service area layer to include more than one facility, but this one covers two facilities, which is incorrect.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of what is going wrong/what to do to fix the issue?

Edit: I tried using the detailed service area polygons and used lines + polygons, and it looks a lot better.

[image]

I have been adjusting the polygon trim distance to see how that changes things, and it does make things more accurate. However, there is an issue.

Areas in the center of blocks, which are not directly accessible by the street network show up beyond the threshold they are supposed to. As such, the centroids of the census blocks will be in the wrong polygon. Is there any way to merge segments like these in the middle of blocks to the polygons that surround them without doing it manually, one by one?

Also, if you look at the two images below, you will notice something weird. The two purple circles are subway entrances-one at the northeast corner of Nostrand Avenue and President Street, and one at the northwest corner of that intersection. For whatever reason, areas on the east side of Nostrand Avenue (the north-south street in between the two entrances), are shown as part of the polygon for the northwest corner, which does not make any sense, as it would take less time for people on the east side of the street to get to the entrance at the northeast corner. Does anyone have any idea of what is going wrong/what to do to fix the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the underlying network that the service areas are built from? May be you have topological errors, overlapping line, breaks, incorrect one-ways etc etc.?

Comment: The underlying network is the Street LION file with ferries and highways excluded, as per this tutorial (https://github.com/CenterForSpatialResearch/gis_tutorials/blob/master/28_Creating_a_Service_Area.md).

Comment: Have a look at the [metadata](https://www1.nyc.gov/assets/planning/download/pdf/data-maps/open-data/lion_metadata.pdf?r=21a) . It seems to have many different Segment Types and even states in the data quality section that lines can duplicate. Are you filtering and quality controlling the network before you attempt your analysis?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had filtered out streets where pedestrians can not go. Is there other filtering and quality controlling I should do?